# Combining char to insert into database

Tags: c++, mysql, rfid

The codes shown below displays the tag data on the monitor. What i need is to combine all the character in "t" and insert it into the database. what happens in the code below is that everytime it loops, it prints the characters into mysql into a different entry. For example: if the hexadecimal tag length is 10 bytes long, it will be in 10 different entries. I need to somehow combine the characters and insert it into 1 entry.

I have tried making it into string, but the first argument of sprintf() "Query[256]" is required to be of character declaration hence it gives me an error.

Btw the codes below is displaying tags being read from a RFID reader.

```
void CT1121Dlg::DisplayTagData(int cnt,int tag_len,int start_index)

{
MYSQL *pConnection;
MYSQL_RES *pResult=NULL; 
MYSQL_ROW Row;
char Query[256];
int a;
int z = 25; 
int fields;
pConnection = mysql_init(NULL);
mysql_real_connect(pConnection,"localhost","root","password","test",0,NULL,0); 


    CString s,s0;

    int i,j;

    unsigned char t;


for(i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
    {   
        s.Format("NO.%d: ",start_index+i+1);
        for(j = 0; j < tag_len; j++)
        {
            t = IdBuf[i].Ids[j];



            if(t < 0x10)
            {
                s0.Format("0%X ",t); // if hexa is less than 10 print 0 infront of it



            }
            else
                s0.Format("%X ",t); // else just print the 2 bit hexa decimal


            s += s0;
        **sprintf(Query, "INSERT into t(e) values (%x)",t);**

        if ( mysql_query(pConnection,Query) == 0 )
    {
        pResult = mysql_store_result( pConnection );    
        }

        }



        AddOprationInfo(s); // print string s on the screen


    }

 }
```

Comment: I would recommend that you change your password, now that you've posted it publicly on the internet. Especially if you use the same password elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You are using MFC, I think: just declare Query as CString, and use Format, as in all other places you are already doing.

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried making it into string, but the first argument of
>   sprintf() "Query[256]" is required to be of character declaration
>   hence it gives me an error.

Just cast it to a char * by using (char*)Query instead of just Query.